# CSS3 button style without hand cursor

Tags: html, css

I want to try to simulate a button with HTML5 and CSS3.

This is my CSS style:

```
.shiny-btn {
    background-color: #CE401C;
    border: thin solid #882D13;
    border-radius: 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em 0.7em;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #BBBBBB;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    width: 15em;
}
```

And this is my HTML5 code:

```
<a id="spanishButton" class="shiny-btn" onclick="setLanguage('spanish');">Spanish</a>
```

Why I can't see a hand cursor button if I'm using `<a>` tag?

Comment: I threw in the `html` and `css` tags anyway so this gets a little more traffic, as `<a>` isn't as often associated with the new HTML5 as it is with the HTML we've known for decades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an `href` attribute to your `a` element:

```
<a href="#" id="spanishButton" class="shiny-btn" onclick="setLanguage('spanish');return false">Spanish</a>
```

Then you'll be able to see the default `pointer` cursor for `a` elements, which is what I gather you want.

---

As you requested in the comments, that site is doing with this CSS:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

If you include that, you don't need the `href` attribute.

Comment: So that "can" turned out to be a typo after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question: here, http://papermashup.com/demos/css-buttons/, I can see a hand cursor but they don't have a href="#". Do you know why?

Comment: As an added goodie: typical default styles are `body { cursor: default; } a { cursor: inherit; } a:link { cursor: pointer; }`, hence the relationship between a hand/pointer cursor and `<a>` elements with the `href` attribute.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks, I never did know the reason behind the `href` magic.

Comment: `:link` targets elements with the `href` attribute, so that's how it all comes together :) Also, `a { cursor: inherit; }` is implicit, but I'm just making it clear they inherit cursor styles by default.

Answer (score 2):

`$cursor:pointer;` is the default behaviour of a `<a>` tag.

If you want to prevent the page from displaying a pointer, you should use:

```
.shiny-btn{
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but using this I only see a pointer arrow.

Comment: @vansfannel, what do you want to achieve then?

Comment: Sorry, I want to see a hand cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If this element is not used as a link, but to trigger an event, or bit of javascript please consider using a button element.

To answer your question,

```
cursor: pointer;
```

is correct.